# I want smooth animation on live server for image sequence scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using `canvas` for this animation. The animation is working fine on localhost but on the live servers it's taking too much time.

This is because I'm using almost 3000 frames for this animation, all frames are important. How can I increase the loading speed on the live server?

I have attached the code. Please review it and help me if I'm wrong somewhere.

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const frameCount = 2999;
const currentFrame = index => (`compressed/${index.toString().padStart(9, '720_0000')}.jpg`)
const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
img.onload = function() {
  scaleToFill(this);
}

function scaleToFill(img) {
  var scale = Math.max(canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height);
  var x = (canvas.width / 2) - (img.width / 2) * scale;
  var y = (canvas.height / 2) - (img.height / 2) * scale;
  context.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
```

```html
<canvas id="hero-lightpass"></canvas>
```

Comment: You are trying to load THREE THOUSAND individual images, to show one single animation? _"How can I increase the loading speed on the live server?"_ - by using a _video_ instead ...?

Comment: You can convert it into a video and then use compression tools to make it light weight

Comment: is there any solution for this type of animation? please help..

Comment: Research 'Sprite sheets'.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you... but actually, I'm using full-size images like viewport. and I think the sprite sheet is just for animated characters. Right?

Comment: A sprite sheet is for any form of multi-frame image animation. It doesn't matter what the subject or size is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan okay let me research.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177261/i-want-section-wise-division-on-canvas-loop

Answer (score 0):

There might be some edge cases where you still need individual images, and the suggestions in the comments (using video or Sprite sheets) will not do, if you can use one of those option you should, it will simplify a lot...

---

I'm going to focus on that edge case where we have a ton of images

Great examples how to do things like that are online maps:

- Google maps (https://www.google.com/maps)
- OpenStreetMap (https://www.openstreetmap.org/)

Those maps have a lot of images, but they do not download all at once, they download and draw only what is needed, in your case you can preload maybe 50 *(you have to experiment to see what best)* and download the 51, 52 ... as you are drawing the first you have preloaded.

Back to the maps; They use "small" map tiles to paint one big mosaic, here are a couple of tiles:

- https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/6/16/25.png
- https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/6/15/26.png

You can see they are coming from different servers `a` & `b` that is to speed up download, browsers have limits on how many images are downloaded from one server at a time, for more details see:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-server

---

In a nutshell:

- Download and draw only what is needed
- Use multiple servers to host your images